# How to write back to my file

Tags: python, csv

I'm parsing a CSV file using python, but I'm not able to write back to the file after the modifications that I perform. I'm exporting the CSV in this way:

```
def read_file(self):
    with open(self.file) as f:
        parse_data=[row  for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',',quotechar=('\"'), skipinitialspace=True)]
        return parse_data
```

When I try to write the CSV to a different file, I'm not able to complete the task. I already tried to write back with `csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',quotechar=('\"'))` but I'm not able to perform it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't edit a file that's open for reading only.

> **open**(*file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None*)
>
> 'r'   open for reading (default)

In order to read the file as well as add to it you'll need to open with `a+`

```
with open(file.txt, 'a+') as f:
    # Your code here
```

When you need to write to it, use `f.write()` within the loop.